# Add Value Range to DWORD in Registry

Tags: ftp, windows-registry, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm following the instructions on this KB article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/975710

Under resolution, it tells me to add something into the registry with the following information:

```
Location:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WDSServer\Providers\WDSTFTP

Name: MaximumBlockSize 
Type: (REG_DWORD) 
Value range: 512–1456 
Base: (Decimal)
```

When I create the DWORD value, it doesn't let me put in the range of "512-1456". The value is set to decimal instead of hex, I'm just not sure how to add the entire range since it doesn't let you add a hyphen.

**How can I add the entire range required for this fix?**

Server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's asking you to select a single value in the range specified, so you'd enter a single number from 512 to 1456 (inclusive). I'd go with the highest value permitted to reduce network traffic.